# Oracle does not update WebLogic security patch anymore?

Tags: security, weblogic

Recently I've learned that some versions of WebLogic contain critical vulnerabilities:

https://vulmon.com/searchpage?q=oracle+weblogic+server+14.1.1.0.0

But after I checked on Oracle's official website for information on Weblogic, I found that the newest version is still 12.2.1.4 and 14.1.1.0.0:

https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/weblogic-server-installers-downloads.html

Can someone explain this? Does Oracle provide some secret ways to update their Weblogic or they dont maintain it anymore?

Comment: This is off-topic, but Oracle still issues [Critical Patch Updates](https://www.oracle.com/security-alerts/#CriticalPatchUpdates) for WebLogic. The base release hasn't been updated but you patch on top of that (if you have a support contract, anyway...).

Answer (score 0):

Only the latest versions of WLS are under Error Correction Policy, meaning that Patch Set Updates will be provided for those versions if you have a Support Contract.

At August 2023, versions under ECP are 12.2.1.4 and 14.1.1.

Previous versions aren't ECP compliant, hence not maintained.

Thus, to minimize the risk of vulnerabilities, make sure to:

1. use a version covered by ECP and
2. use the latest PSU.

References:

Error Correction Support Dates for Oracle WebLogic Server (Doc ID 950131.1)

Patch Set Update (PSU) Release Listing for Oracle WebLogic Server (WLS) (Doc ID 1470197.1)